# Is there a way to force the use of threaded comments or to gray out or block the use of notes, via VBA or otherwise?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a team schedule that gets accesed by many users and we used to use notes to relay information.

With the advent of threaded comments and the company use of Office 365, threaded comments offer timestamps, better replies and locking finished threads.

That said, I still have reticent users.

Is there any way, VBA or otherwise to block the use of notes and only use threaded comments in a workbook?

Note : I have tried a to use VBA to convert notes to comments on close, but it does not include the timestamps which are useful for my managers to keep track requests.

Comment: You can trigger on cell change or select and get the last cell / current cell and check if it has comments... and yell at them

Comment: I'll try the triggers...and good managers don't yell.

Comment: They do when their employee is about to lose their hand in a machine... regardless my intention was to "raise an warning when they added a comment", which I still call "yell" because most people interpret warning boxes as pretty offensive. <I did something wrong? That couldn't possibly be!>